# Xcode - xml google calendar - events today - reader

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, google-calendar-api

I want to parse a google calendar xml URL:
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/123456group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

There are several parser, but they are to extensively. I need just a UIView with some outlets, title, date & description for events today, only. No tableView with cells in a navigationController showing the hole calendar…

In php its quite easy. Some lines of code, but I don't want to parse a php.file on my server with a webView outlet in my app in iOS.

Any ideas how to do that in a small way?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no "small way" to do it...

1. You will need to use a NSConnection to get the XML off the Google Api.
2. You will need to parse it using JSON or NSXmlParser.